# From United States of America or from the United States of America

Tags: word-usage, articles

would you say :
I come from the United States of America
or I come from United States of America ?
same with United Kingdom or the United Kingdom
Thank you for your help !

Comment: Duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127137/need-for-using-the-article-the-before-united-states-of-america

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The USA" versus "USA"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8169/the-usa-versus-usa)